# Недорічний чи недоречний?

Tags: переклад, from-english, різниця-між-словами

Перекладаю слово `preposterous`.

[E2u](https://e2u.org.ua) каже, що слово це перекладається як [`недорічний`](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=preposterous&dicts=all&highlight=on).

У [SUM](http://sum.in.ua) не знаходжу `недорічний`, проте знаходжу [`недоречний`](http://sum.in.ua/s/nedorechnyj).

З одного боку `річний` більше стосується `року`, а `речний`, відповідно, – `речі`, але можу помилятися.

Скажіть, будь ласка, який з варіантів правильний в українській мові.

Про інші переклади типу `абсурдний` знаю, цікавить саме різниця в цих двох словах, зазначених вище.

P.S. [Словники України](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) знаходять тільки `недоречний`. Можна вважати саме це слово правильним?

Comment: Багато разів чув і бачив саме "недоречно", але у словниках не перевіряв.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Слово *недорічний* наводиться як тлумачення до «абсурдний» в [УЗЕ](https://uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0:Ukrayinska_zahalna_entsyklopediya_Red._I._Rakovskyy_(T._1.;_A-Zh)_(1935).djvu/13), зустрічається у «[Роксоляні](https://uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0:%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA_%D0%9E._%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0_(1930).djvu/152)» Назарука, «[Сучасному літописі](http://www.i-franko.name/uk/Verses/DavnjeJNove/IzZlobyDnja/SuchasnyjLitopys/6Maj.html)» і перекладах Франка (згадується [тут](https://chasopys-rich.com.ua/2016/08/19/690/)), «[Вірі і науці](https://zbruc.eu/node/62414)» Йосифа Сліпого, «[Легендах старокиївських](http://www.rulit.me/books/legendi-starokiivski-read-293710-69.html)» Наталени Королевої, [аналізі](http://shron.chtyvo.org.ua/Kopach_Ivan/Krytychna_analiza_tzv_Tukydydovoi_Arkheologii.pdf) Івана Копача і — що цікаво — [наводиться](http://www.svoboda-news.com/arxiv/pdf/1940/Svoboda-1940-283.pdf) як російське слово у газеті «Свобода», яка виходила в Джерсі і Нью-Йорку, де пропонуються замінники *нестійний, безглуздий*, але в пізнішому випуску [вживається](https://archive.org/stream/Svoboda-1967-098#page/n1/mode/2up) і просто в тексті. 
Усі наведені тексти датуються 1901—1967 роками (включно зі згаданим словником Андрусишена і Крета 1955-го, [наведеного](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=preposterous&dicts=all&highlight=on) на e2u), і якщо слово не потрапило у пізніші словники, то можна припустити, що не прижилося.

Натомість *недоречний* у словниках є ([СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/nedorechnyj), [Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/32272-nedorechnyj.html), вісьмох на [r2u](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)) і вживається часто.